# Can my theory work for letting the swinging work?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, perpetual-motion

This is my theory, will it stop after few hours? why would it stop? i have on top S to S to repel then i have N S to attract, to produce random force for the swing. Then i have large N N repel to push the swing.

Can my theory work for the swing to play 24 hour?

**EDIT:**  attached A (theory), B (practical), C (correction to repeat loop programming)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not quite sure where you expect to find those magnetic monopoles, but I think you've neglected to account for friction.

Comment: Can you talk about what is happening in more detail? Are there two swings, each with two monopoles and one dipole? Can they pass each other, or will they collide? Or is there one swing an a sort of fixed arm?

Comment: I still find it very unclear what you're asking here. If I take a look at your diagram, what I think would happen is the middle S and N will just stick together, as well as the bottom ones, and the top ones will just jiggle against eachother before eventually stopping. 

You have to precise what is your "system". What is the timer about ? Is the swing rigid, or a rope ?

Comment: No it is not possible, since "S" and "N" magnets do not exist; all magnets have a North and South pole.

Comment: How do your magnets (ignoring the monopole issue) differ in their effect from simple springs?

Comment: I can use outer coil logic to on magnets to produce energy on springs not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you start in a non-equilibrium state (i.e., you pull the magnets apart), the system will jiggle about in some fashion to begin with. Over time, loss of energy to friction$^*$ will lead to the amplitude of the oscillation getting smaller until it finally stops in a lowest energy state.

So just like any other swing, basically.

$^*$air resistance, bending and stretching in the cables, induced electrical resistive loss.